# Not able to insert Stripe Connect response into Mongodb using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-connect

I am struggling to insert Stripe Connect response into my users collection (Mongodb) using Node Js.
I have been following the link to get the response from Stripe Connect.
https://gist.github.com/padolsey/7109113

The response I am getting is below (have altered for security purpose)

```
{ 
  access_token: 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  livemode: false,
  refresh_token: 'rt_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  stripe_publishable_key: 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  stripe_user_id: 'acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  scope: 'read_write' 
}
```

Using Mongoose I need to insert this response into my Users collection. This is what I am doing.

```
userObj.update({"_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)},
            {$set: {
                      stripe : stripeData,
                 }
            },
            function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);

                } else {
                    res.jsonp{'message': 'Stripe Account connected sucessfully!'}
                }

            });
```

Where stripeData is the response from Stripe Connect.
Also note that my user is been connected to Stripe successfully but unable to insert or update the response data on users collection.
What wrong i am doing here ? Have given lot of time on this but without success.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `update()` if what you want to do is an insertion?

Comment: I already have a user collection, need to update that collection with the response.

Comment: When I am hard coding the response, it is getting updated to user collection, but no success with Stripe response.

Comment: Is there any error you are getting?

Comment: @titi23 - No errors getting, and unfortunately response data is not been saved.

Comment: Have you tried doing find with `{"_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}` query? Are you getting any record?

Comment: @titi23 - Yes tried that too. No success yet

Comment: @Aman so doing find with the query is not giving result?